# Binary relations: are these relations transitive and relative?

Tags: relations, binary

Let's say we have $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $S \subseteq A^2$, and $S = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$ Is it transitive and symmetric? Why is it so?

I have had a doubt about it being symmetric as I understood the symmetry that it would need two pairs like (a,b) (b,a), and I am not sure it applies for pair (a,a).

As for transitivity, I've seen it needs (a,b) (b,c) and (a,c) but in this case we do not have the element for 'b', so (a,c) pair doesn't exist and my question is, if the rule does apply when you do not have appropriate pair for it.

And about transitivity if $B=\{2,3,4,5,6\}$, $R \subseteq B^2$, and $R= \{(2,4), (3,6)\}$ if it is transitive or not? Why?

Comment: What are the clauses, $S\in R$ and $R\in S$, meant to express?

Comment: Actually it was S relation is for the A, and R is for the B.

Comment: Then what you wanted to say is $S\subseteq A^2$ and $R\subseteq B^2$.

Comment: Then state that.  Don't use the "in" symbol.  It's confusing, its unnecessary and I don't know of any text that *doesn't* use $\in $ to be the "in" statement, so it's out and out wrong.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am just new to thid website and didn't get acquainted to formatting yet.

Comment: Why do you not understand the definitions?  If you apply the definitions the answer is clear.  So please explain where you are having trouble.

Comment: @fleablood, Zhenia originally used the € symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relation $\mathcal R$ is transitive over the set $\mathcal A$ if $$\forall x{\in}\mathcal A~\forall y{\in}\mathcal A~\forall z{\in}\mathcal A: \big((x,y){\in}\mathcal R\wedge (y,z){\in}\mathcal R~\to~ (x,z){\in}\mathcal R\big)$$

A relation $\mathcal R$ would *not* be transitive over the set $\mathcal A$ if a counter example exists in the form: $$\exists x{\in}\mathcal A~\exists y{\in}\mathcal A~\exists z{\in}\mathcal A: \big((x,y){\in}\mathcal R\wedge (y,z){\in}\mathcal R\wedge (x,z){\notin}\mathcal R\big)$$

So, can you find such a counter example in either case?

---

A relation $\mathcal R$ is symmetric (over the base set $\mathcal A$) if: $$\forall x{\in}\mathcal A~\forall y{\in}\mathcal A:\big((x,y){\in}\mathcal R \to (y,x){\in}\mathcal R\big) $$

A relation $\mathcal R$ would *not* be symmetric (over the base set $\mathcal A$) if a counter example exists in the form: $$\exists x{\in}\mathcal A~\exists y{\in}\mathcal A:\big((x,y){\in}\mathcal R\wedge (y,x){\notin}\mathcal R\big) $$

So, can you find such a counter example in either case?